# ImagePullBackOff issue bitnami rabbitmq-exporter , in k8s pods

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rabbitmq, debian, bitnami

We are facing an issue that fails to download the bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter from Dockrhub.

kubectl  get statefulset rabbitmq -o yaml

```
 name: rabbitmq
        - name: RABBIT_URL
          value: http://localhost:15672
        - name: RABBIT_USER
          value: user
        - name: PUBLISH_PORT
          value: "9419"
        - name: RABBIT_CAPABILITIES
          value: bert,no_sort
        image: docker.io/bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter:0.29.0-debian-9-r104
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 6
          httpGet:
            path: /metrics
            port: metrics


 name: RABBITMQ_ERL_COOKIE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: rabbitmq-erlang-cookie
              name: rabbitmq
        - name: RABBITMQ_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: rabbitmq-password
              name: rabbitmq
        image: docker.io/bitnami/rabbitmq:3.8.2-debian-9-r0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
```

but we have issue with the RabbitMQ matrics.

```
# kubectl get pods --selector app=rabbitmq

NAME         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
rabbitmq-0   1/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          5d15h
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
pod status 

rabbitmq-0                                             1/2     ImagePullBackOff             0                 5d15h
redis-master-0                                         2/2     Running                      0                 5d15h
```

It's not available in Docker Hub.

```
docker pull bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter:0.29.0-debian-9-r104
```

Error response from daemon: pull access denied for bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

So , we are faild to download the bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter specific version as it is not available in the docker Hub.

Which version of RabbitMQ is required to access /bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter? Presently, we are utilizing /bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter. Has the exporter been replaced with harbor-exporter in their Helm charts? If we upgrade to the recent version of the bitnami/rabbitmq Helm chart , which version of exporter is avibale to use ?

Would anyone be able to offer suggestions to address this issue? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What sort of help are you looking for? The image you want no longer exists. You will need to either find a replacement or build one yourself.

Comment: rabbitmq-exporter:0.29.0-debian-9-r104 is not availabe , what is the alternative to be used for ? compitable with bitnami/rabbitmq:3.8.2-debian-9-r0 ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the image doesn't exist in the public docker repo and I think it has changed. See [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/14a39389182cb2f55b95ecc29f119f1dff039c0e/bitnami/harbor/values.yaml#L3171) , looks like the exporter has changed to harbor-exporter from their helm charts

Comment: bitnami/harbor-exporter. This component exposes Harbor metrics in Prometheus format  On the other hand, bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter is a Docker image that provides a simple way to export RabbitMQ metrics to Prometheus. https://bitnami.com/stack/harbor-exporter , Is this will work for /bitnami/rabbitmq:3.8.2-debian-9-r0 ? or need to change the tag to tag: 3.12.2-debian-11-r5 ?